# Wearable DataClient onDataChanged is never called

Tags: android, wear-os, google-datalayer, dataitem

I am building a wear os app as part of a react native project. The handheld application should send some data among it's wearable-nodes whenever it is changed. I am using DataClient and DataItems to do this. On the wearable side I have implemented DataClient.OnDataChangedListener, this is never called though.

This is the method that gets called when the data is changed. I get the onSucces message so I assume this works:

```
@ReactMethod
public void updateData(String name, Integer age, String description){
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/data");
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String timestamp = tsLong.toString();

    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("Timestamp", timestamp);
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("Name", name);
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt("Age", age);
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("Description", description);

    PutDataRequest dataRequest = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
    dataRequest.setUrgent();
    Task<DataItem> putDataTask = Wearable.getDataClient(reactContext).putDataItem(dataRequest);

    putDataTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataItem dataItem) {
            System.out.println("Great Succes!");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the onDataChanged method of the DataClient on the wearable side.

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    System.out.println("DATA CHANGED");
    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/data") == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                System.out.println(dataMap.getString("Name"));
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
        }
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies in the gradle files for the handheld:

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}

wearApp project(':watch')
}
```

And the dependencies in the gradle files for the wearable:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'


compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.7.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.7.0'
}
```

So again, the onDataChanged is never called and I can't find the problem. I've tried several things.

- The package name and application id is the same
- I added a timestamp (as you can see) so the DataItem is truly different each time
- On the handheld side I implemented a method that lists the connected nodes using NodeClient. The smartwatch is always listed as connected node'
- I also tried to implement a DataLayerListeningService, but that also doesn't fire. Same problem I guess.

Since Google changed a lot on it's DataLayer API a lot of information about this has become irrelevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The problem was that the watch application was not signed with the same key as the handheld app. After I did this, it worked instantly!